# Web Pages doesn't load if print dialog box is closed

Tags: javascript, html

I have given a link to print a particular **div** of the page in the below html code

```
<a href=\"printpage\" onClick=\"printthis(); return false;\">Print this page</a></center>
```

**The JavaScript used is given below**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printthis()
{

    var w = window.open('', '', 'width=1200,height=600,resizeable,scrollbars');
    w.document.write($("#printthis").html());
    w.document.close(); // needed for chrome and safari
    javascript:w.print();
    w.close();
}
</script>
```

If I click on the link, the print dialog box is opening and clicking on the print button is printing the document. But if I close the dialog box without printing or cancelling, the other **tabs of the website are not working(loading)** . I have to close the window and reopen it to make it work. What might be the reason

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "the other web pages are not loading"?

Comment: Once i close the dialog box.....the web pages of my project are not getting refreshed

Comment: Do you mean the link does not direct to `printpage/` after click?

Comment: Actually the printing is happening......That is not a problem but if user chooses not to print and close the dialog box, then the other pages are not getting refreshed....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not getting refreshed. Why would they refresh? Where is your code to refresh them?

Comment: I meant, once user closes the dialog box, the other tabs of the website are not working upon clicking them

Comment: I dont see any issue with the script you have attached in the question. Do you have any other script in the page? Something is causing the browser to be unresponsive.

Comment: Before adding this snippet to the page, everything was working fine. I don't think there is problem with the other scripts in the page

Comment: Sounds like a strange browser-specific bug. Can you tell us what browser(s) have you used to test and replicate this behavior?